# TortoiseSVN hangs with .vbproj file on initial import to repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, collabnet, vb.net

we have a CollabNet Subversion Edge server running on a Windows server. Subversion Server is configured to serve via https. 
When trying to import a Visual Studio project folder with TortoiseSVN it hangs when adding the project file (.vbproj).

Test 1: It happens exactly the same when the server is configured to serve via http.
Test 2: Importing any project folder using the console utility (svn) works fine.

Both these tests lead to the conclusion that there is neither a network nor authorization problem.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Versions running:
Visual Studio 2005
Collabnet Subversion Edge 2.0.0-2190.74 + Subversion 1.6.17-2190.74

Answer (score -1):

Give uberSVN (http://www.uberSVN.com a try.   We use a similar configuration and don't have any issues.

Comment: I'm not sure this counts as a good answer... especially when you respond with "We use..."

It makes it seem more like product placement.